# Firestore not-equal (!=) count as range filter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the not-equal (!=) operator in a query that already has a range filter (geohash query), thinking this should behave the same as an equal (==) query.

But upon running that query, I get prompted with this error message:

> Unhandled Exception: The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([location, geohash]), false]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([expire_at])" when an inequality operator is invoked.

Now, I understand that, due to how indexes works, firestore only allow ONE range filter per query. What I don't understand is why the `not-equal` operation here is considered a range filter.

In other words: Is the `not-equal` operation just synthetic sugar for `.where(x > y).where(x < y)` ?

Comment: Are you able to provide more detail? Perhaps the query you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

`orderBy` is used to help filter and process the index's so you get the most relevant to your needs. So the error is that the fields for the `orderBy` must be related to the `where` `inequality` field.

You must use an `orderBy` on the `inequality` field first, just make sure the correct compound queries are generated.